# Multiple includes in php not displaying in browser

Tags: php

I have multiple php includes in my index.php file, but they will not display.  If I only have 1 include, then it works fine.  The problem occurs when I have more than 1 include.

For example, my index.php has the following lines:

```
<?php
require ('tool5vminmax.php');
require ('tool3vminmax.php');
?>
```

And when I access my index.php file, the two includes are not displayed.  If I remove one of he includes, then it is displayed just fine.

Each one of those files is a HighChart, with the code below:

```
    <?php
        require_once('database.php');
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT SerialNumber, MAX(v2) as v1, MIN(v2) as min from Statistics GROUP by SerialNumber;");
        $result = array('SerialNumber' => array(), 'v1' => array(), 'min' => array());
        if ($stmt) {
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $SerialNumber, $v1, $min);
            while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
                $result['SerialNumber'][] = $SerialNumber;
                $result['v1'][] = (float)$v1;
                $result['min'][] = (float)$min;
            }
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

?>
<body>
        <div id="div-chart"></div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>


        <script>
                $(function () {
                    $('#div-chart').highcharts({
                        chart: {
                            type: 'spline'
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Tool +3.3v Max and Min'
                        },
                        subtitle: {
                            text: 'SubTitle'
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            categories: <?php echo json_encode($result['SerialNumber']) ?>,
                            crosshair: true
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            min: 0,
                            title: {
                                text: 'Voltage'
                            }
                        },
                                                                                                              },
                        plotOptions: {
                            column: {
                                pointPadding: 0.01,
                                borderWidth: 0
                            }
                        },
                        series: [{
                            name: 'Maximum',
                            data: <?php echo json_encode($result['v1']) ?>
                        }, {
                            name: 'Minimum',
                            data: <?php echo json_encode($result['min']) ?>
}]
                    });
                });
        </script>
</body>
```

Comment: its probably the invalid html that is the problem - in the browser view source.

Comment: What is invalid @nogad. HTML5 is pretty liberal.

Comment: any errors in the php error log?

Comment: browsers are remarkably tolerant but this code will end up with 2 body tags. need to check source, as i said, to see if that's an issue or not.

Answer (score 2):

Well, yeah, if both of those files output the same html, then

```
<body>
    <div id="div-chart"></div>
```

is outright invalid. You cannot have multiple `<body>` tags in a single HTML document, and `id` values **MUST** be unique. If you have multiple duplicate IDs, only the FIRST one found by getElementById() will ever be returned, and all the others get ignored.

Comment: agreed - there may indeed be both of them showing up but only one chart is printing since they both update the same div#div-chart

Comment: I removed both the body tag and assigned unique ID's but the charts still do not display.  Other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It was a combination of removing the BODY tags, assigning a unique DIV ID, and moving my SCRIPT SRC tags to the head of my index.php

Works well now!

Comment: This shouldn't be an edit, because it's a solution to the problem and thus should be in an answer.